# IOS/Objective-C: Filter FetchedObjects Using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I am trying to filter some fetchedobjects (a large number of contacts) in an array using NSPredicate.  The predicate takes an array of ids such as (2,3,4,5,6,5,000) and is supposed to find all cases where the uid in the contact in the fetchedObjects or array of contacts, is present in the list of ids.

My filter should return some objects but is returning 0.  Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with the code?  Is it the NSPredicate possibly or is there something wrong with my arrays?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.uid IN %@", uids];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:fetchedObjects];
 //No objects though there should be some       
NSArray<Contacts*>* mycontacts = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I am looking for an `NSPredicate` that would return all the objects in the `fetchedObjects` that have a `uid` that is in the array `uids`.  For example, if I have three objects in the array as follows, I'd like the predicate to return the first two where the `uid` (2 or 3) is found in the array (2,3,4,5,6,5,000) but not return the third where the `uid` (333) is not present in the array :

```
uid|first|last
2|Bob|Jones
3|Mary|Smith
333|John|Doe
```

Edit 2:

Fetched objects is an array of contacts, I think, created from a fetchedResultsController that has executed a fetch of managed objects from Core Data.  I attempt to make the array that I sort an array of contacts as well with the syntax `NSArray<Contacts*>* mycontacts` but perhaps I am doing this wrong...

```
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

                        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                       // abort();
                    }
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
```

Comment: What the class of objects in `uids`. What's the class of objects `uid` in your `fetchedObjects` objects? Because if they don't match, that clearly explains the issue. Else, either you can fix the mismatch classes, or you can build a NSPredicate with block.

Comment: See some additional code above.  I'm trying to make the classes the same but maybe not succeeding.

Comment: What is the class of a property `uid` of `Contacts` object? `NSNumber` of `NSString`? How is created your array `uids`?